# TcpClient for Zebra Not Disconnecting: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Tags: c#, sockets, connection, tcpclient, zebra-printers

I am using `TcpClient` to connect to a Zebra label printer, then send a glob of ZPL code, then disconnect, repeat. This continues for dozens of labels.

The code that print a single label is as follows:

```
client = new TcpClient();                      
client.Connect(networkAddress, port);          
writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()); 
writer.Write(content);                         
writer.Flush();                                

if (client.Client.Connected)                   // Excessive levels of unnecessary
    client.Client.Disconnect(false);           //   disconnecting and disposing 
client.Close();                                //   for testing purposes
writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();
```

After a couple dozen labels print, I get this exception:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I run `netstat` and see that I'm maintaining a couple dozen `TIME_WAIT` status connections to the printer, each on a different local port. `TIME_WAIT` means my machine has tried to disconnect but the printer is waiting to see if there are any remaining packets to be sent.

What is standard operating procedure for this? I don't think I can wait until the time period elapses because I think that's in the minutes. I changed the code to this to reuse the socket:

```
//client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(networkAddress, port);          
writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()); 
writer.Write(content);                         
writer.Flush();                                

if (client.Client.Connected)
    client.Client.Disconnect(true); // Changed to true
//client.Close();
writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();
```

But I get this error the second time I iterate over `client.Connect()`.

```
A connect request was made on an already connected socket.
```

What's a handsome fellow such as myself to do in this situation?

Comment: I have the same problem ! Have u find a solution ? Thankyou

Comment: @MrRubix: Sadly, I don't think we ever solved this issue. Every method we tried produced the same results in production, but we couldn't re-create the issue at will in development.